# 404 error Occurred in linode server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Codeigniter 404 error Occurred in linode server. 
How to fix it?

I changed the following in `conf.php`

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

`.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php$1 [L]
```

In `apache.conf`:

```
AllowOverride None changed to AllowOverride All
```

but it still does not work.

Comment: Could you provide some more information about your problem? When do you get a 404 error?

Comment: my localhost host work perfectly but not linode server http://45.33.92.123/

Comment: #UnnecessaryOutOfTopicTIP - Do not use linode. Use EC2

Comment: I get a 404 in 45.33.92.123/index.php that means that the file has not been uploaded. Like **literally**